# Cyclic dependency detected (MongoDB Atlas Index)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial, pymongo-3.x

I created a MongoDB database using Python and now would like to set indexes for the location field for geospatial queries. The location field looks as follows

```
location{type:"Point", coordinates :[lat, lng]}
```

I keep getting the above error whenever I try to create the index on location field using MongoDB Atlas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved. I changed lat, lng to lng, lat in the coordinates and it worked.